# Oracle Data Modeler Scripts Stopped Working

Tags: scripting, oracle-sql-data-modeler

The scripts in newer Oracle Data Modeler seems to have stopped working. Even though the Oracle Nashorn is selected as the Scripting engine, it's not working with the newer version of data modeler. Not sure what settings needs to be enabled for the scripting to work?

This is for version 21.4.1, the one which was release in December - 2021.

[image]

Comment: Just use Java 11 instead of Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Oracle Data Modeler 21.4.1.349
OS host is Oracle Linux 7
JDK is 1.8.251

After updating version of Data Modeler I got error message after try run of Design Rules "Oracle Nashorn scripting engine does not exist. Script evaluation is terminated.".